# How to open a project in Package Explorer for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

[image][image]I am new at using Eclipse and learning android so last time i was coding i made an application and in the package explorer( i think that's the name ) everything was visible but restarting again today i see nothing and dont know what i did! The entire package is empty and when i go to open i can only bring one window up. 
These are the folders

- AndroidManifest.xml
- src
- res
- drawable-hdpi
- layout
- values

I can open AndroidManifest but not through the Package Explorer through file!
i am comfortable with seeing all those folders and want to get it back!

Comment: Click the little arrow mark before the folder's and it will expand...

Comment: no not that!
my entire package is EMPTY!!!!!!! NOTHING IN IT!

Comment: Place image of the screen, so i can able to help you.

Comment: ok i did!! the top one is what i dont want!!!
but normally the ---><--- ISNT SELECTED! but i had to crop out what i had there in the second pic!!!
so thats what i get and i want to see all my folders in the second pic

Comment: Try, closing the package explorer and Goto Window --> Show View --> Package Explorer.

Comment: well it opened back nothing but i found a way to get the folder ( by deleting my project and starting a new one ) all i want to know is if someone sends you a project how to do open everything in package explorer?

Comment: Sorry, i can't get you... `all i want to know is if someone sends you a project how to do open everything in package explorer?`.

Comment: like all the files! like src, layout! like if someone sent you a project they were working on how do you open it up on package explorer

Comment: Dont let this conversation leads long, in this manner we have to talk in chat, i think you didnt get that privilege yet. If someone send a project to me means i will put the folder into my workspace, then in package explrer right click and import and select the existing project and browse the location of the workspace and importing it. Thats all...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same workspace?

- If no switch workspace: 
  File > Switch Workspace
- If yes, somehow your project removed from it. So re-import it from:
  File > Import > Android > Existing Android Project into workspace